# Executing a script in the current tab, from within a popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So after being properly educated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975535/writing-to-current-tab-console-from-the-extension-popup/25976711?noredirect=1#comment40782569_25976711) and moving a little bit further with developing Chrome Extensions, it seems that I need more direction on how to move forward.

```
function testFunction() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
    var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, {file: "test.js"});
});
```

The test.js contains my script. It works fine when messing around with basic things like console.log and changing background colors, but does not seem to work for the pre-made script Im trying to use. Like I mentioned in my previous thread, the script I have works well when I simply paste it in the console - and I want the extension to do just that.
I was probably wrong at first when I said that the script does not depend on anything on the page.

What exactly is happening when running code via the console, and how can I run the same code via an extension?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the path to your JS file to the manufest/"permissions" array? Sometimes you may also need to add this path to manufest/"web_accessible_resources"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works differently in the console and in the content script, because Chrome creates a separate, [isolated JavaScript context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) for each extension's scripts.

There are many reasons for it, not least security: the page cannot affect a script running in the higher-privilege extension context. Also, it means that there are no clashes between code used by the page and the script. For more information, see the link above.

---

When you execute code in the console, you can notice a drop-down above the console, which by default reads `<top frame>`. This is where you select which context to execute commands in. If there is a context script injected from any extension, you will see its context there too.

The script you mention refers to the JavaScript objects already defined on the page; this is why it works if you execute it in the console *by default*, but when called from a context script those objects do not exist.

---

So, are those completely isolated? Both contexts have shared access to DOM. This enables content scripts to inject code into the page's context: you can create a `<script>` element and insert it into the page. This will execute the code in the page's context.

For the canonical question covering this topic, see [Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script). This is barely mentioned at all in the official documentation *and frankly blew my mind the first time I saw it's possible*.

So, in your case, you need a content script that acts like a proxy, injecting a page-level script:

```
// content.js - this is what you pass to `executeScript`
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('test.js'); // This is the actual script
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

For this to work, you need to add `test.js` to [web-accessible resources in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) (since the webpage itself will request to load it when you add that `<script>` tag):

```
  "web_accessible_resources" : [ "test.js" ],
```

Comment: Thank you Xan, you have educated me once again. Everything works like a charm!